# How can I implement std::fmt::Display for a custom IntoIterator::Item?

Tags: rust

`LimitedFifoQueue` is a struct that wraps the functionality of a `VecDeque` to limit the number of items it will store at any time:

```
use std::collections::{vec_deque, VecDeque};
use std::fmt;
use std;

#[derive(Debug)]
pub struct LimitedFifoQueue<T> {
    size: usize,
    store: VecDeque<T>,
}

impl<T> LimitedFifoQueue<T> where T: fmt::Display {
    pub fn new(size: usize) -> LimitedFifoQueue<T> {
        LimitedFifoQueue {
            size: size,
            store: VecDeque::with_capacity(size),
        }
    }
    pub fn push(&mut self, elem: T) {
        self.store.push_front(elem);
        if self.store.len() > self.size {
            self.store.pop_back();
        }
    }
    pub fn clear(&mut self) {
        self.store.clear();
    }
}
```

I've implemented the `IntoIterator` trait as follows:

```
impl<T> IntoIterator for LimitedFifoQueue<T> where T: fmt::Display {
    type Item = T;
    type IntoIter = vec_deque::IntoIter<T>;
    fn into_iter(self) -> Self::IntoIter {
        self.store.into_iter()
    }
}
```

And a simplified function that loops through and prints each Item:

```
fn print_all<I>(lines: &I) where I: IntoIterator {
    for string in lines.into_iter() {
        println!("{}", string);
    }
}
```

This gives me the following error:

```
println!("{}", string);
               ^^^^^^ the trait `std::fmt::Display` is not implemented for `<I as std::iter::IntoIterator>::Item`
```

I have created a playground of the code with a full stack trace [here](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=87ad9f1610ce072f04264172d03c13a4&version=stable&backtrace=0).

---

Also, I'm aware that there may be a better way to accomplish what I'm trying to do. I'd love to hear any additional suggestions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> How can I implement `std::fmt::Display` for a custom `IntoIterator::Item`?

You cannot. `Item` might be a type you don't own, and `Display` is a trait you don't own. [You cannot implement a trait you don't own for a type you don't own](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25413201/155423).

All you can do is require that `Item` implements `Display`:

```
fn print_all<I>(lines: I)
    where I: IntoIterator,
          I::Item: fmt::Display, 
{
    for string in lines.into_iter() {
        println!("{}", string);
    }
}
```

You don't need any of the other `T: Display` bounds on your data structure or its methods, as none of those implementations care to print out a value.

Incidentally, `into_iter` is automatically called on the for-loops argument, so you only need to say:

```
fn print_all<I>(lines: I)
    where I: IntoIterator,
          I::Item: fmt::Display, 
{
    for string in lines {
        println!("{}", string);
    }
}
```

You may also wish to review [How to implement Iterator and IntoIterator for a simple struct?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30218886/155423), as you are passing `&lfq` into `print_all`, but `&LimitedFifoQueue` doesn't implement `IntoIterator`, only `LimitedFifoQueue` does. These are different types. You'll need something like

```
impl<'a, T> IntoIterator for &'a LimitedFifoQueue<T> {
    type Item = &'a T;
    type IntoIter = vec_deque::Iter<'a, T>;
    fn into_iter(self) -> Self::IntoIter {
        self.store.iter()
    }
}
```

Comment: Cool, looking at the link now. To clarify: If I'm passing &lfq and need to iterate over it, what traits need to be implemented for LimitedFifoQueue? What do I have to specify in the annotation? Thanks again @Shepmaster

Comment: Okay, I think I'm getting closer... I added the suggested trait implementation and then annotated `print_all` with a lifetime bound, and `&'a I::IntoIter: Iterator` bound. It's now telling me that `&_` does not have the trait Iterator in `print_all`. What gives?   [New Playground Link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=e46d4c5071563f66291267af763b3378&version=stable&backtrace=0)

Comment: @PatrickAllen why did you annotate it with a lifetime bound? The same implementation shown above works.

Comment: Wow. You're right. I just went down a crazy rabbit hole because I had slipped and had `fn print_all(lines: &I)`. Thanks so much :)

Answer (score 2):

This problem has nothing to do with your `IntoIterator` implementation or the rest of your type definition. Just take a look at this code:

```
fn print_all<I>(lines: &I) where I: IntoIterator {
    for string in lines.into_iter() {
        println!("{}", string);
    }
}
```

This piece of code doesn't even know about your `LimitedFifoQueue` type! It takes a value of generic type `I`. What do we know about `I`? It implements `IntoIterator`. Great, what does that tell us about the values the iterator will spit out? Nothing!

So it could be anything, in particular also stuff that doesn't implement `fmt::Display`. So what we want to do is to annotate that the items of the iterator should at least implement `fmt::Display`. How is that done? By adding a bound to the associated type `Item` of the `IntoIterator` trait:

```
fn print_all<I>(lines: &I)
    where I: IntoIterator,
          I::Item: fmt::Display,
{ ... }
```

Once you understand that you can also add bounds to associated items this makes intuitive sense.

After you fixed that error, another error will be reported, about "moving out of borrowed content". This is a fairly standard error, which I won't explain in detail here. But in summary: your `print_all()` function should receive a `I` instead of a `&I`.

Comment: Thanks, very true regarding the &I. I however actually need it to be borrowed as it is owned by another struct. What will be required for me to be able to iterate over this borrowed &lfq?