# Implement `IntoIterator`, changing arrays into structs

Tags: rust

I have a basic struct `ImageData` which, primarily, holds an array of u8s (`bytes`) that represents a PNG image (layed out as rgbrgbrgb... or rgbargbargba...):

```rust
struct ImageData {
    png_type: png::ColorType,
    bytes: Vec<u8>,
    width: u32,
    height: u32,
    is_srgb: bool,
}
```

I also have a `PixelValue` struct that will allow me to treat RGB and RGBA similarly - that is, I want to get `PixelValue`s instead of an array of 3 or 4 `u8`s, because then I would be duplicating a lot of code to deal with those different types.

```rust
struct PixelValue {
    r: u8,
    g: u8,
    b: u8,
    a: u8,
}
```

So I want to implement `IntoIterator` on `ImageData` that will return an iterator on `PixelValue`s. It should convert the `u8` chunks into `PixelValue`s:

```rust
impl<'a> IntoIterator for &'a ImageData {
    type Item = PixelValue;
    type IntoIter = Iter<PixelValue>; // this is definitely wrong

    fn into_iter(self) -> Self::IntoIter {
        let pixel_size = get_pixel_size(self.png_type);  // 3 or 4, depending on RGB or RGBA
        // Need to write something that can take an array of 3 or 4 u8s and returns the PixelValue
        self.bytes.chunks(pixel_size).map(|ar| PixelValue(ar))
    }
}
```

My questions are:

- Am I going in the right direction? Can I change the output value (`Item`) of the iterator with `map`? If not, why not?
- Is there an obvious "best practice" way to go about this problem (turning an array of pixel rgb or rgba's into structs)?

Comment: One limitation with Rust (currently) is that you can't use `impl Trait` in traits, so you end up either having to quite frustratingly define the `IntoIter` associated type rather unwieldily (something like `Map<Chunks<Iter<'a, u8>>, fn(&[u8]) -> PixelValue>` and ensure the "closure" doesn't capture any environment so that its type can be "promoted" to a `fn` pointer) or (often more preferably) you define your own struct implementing `Iterator` and return that.

Comment: If your pixel value structs are `#[repr(C)]` then you can cast a slice's data pointer to a struct reference (in unsafe code) and avoid the conversion altogether.

Comment: @cdhowie: How would a `[u8; 3]` (in the case of data without the alpha channel) be casted to `PixelValue`?

Comment: @eggyal There would need to be an RGB version of the struct to do that. I assumed OP had a different struct for different pixel layouts, as is common when doing this kind of work.

Answer (score 2):

You can use dynamic dispatch, wrapping the iterator in a `Box`:

```rust
struct ImageData {
    png_type: u8,
    bytes: Vec<u8>,
    width: u32,
    height: u32,
    is_srgb: bool,
}

struct PixelValue {
    r: u8,
    g: u8,
    b: u8,
    a: u8,
}

impl<'a> IntoIterator for &'a ImageData {
    type Item = PixelValue;
    type IntoIter = Box<dyn Iterator<Item = Self::Item> + 'a>;

    fn into_iter(self) -> Self::IntoIter {
        let size = 3;
        Box::new(self.bytes.chunks(size).map(move |chunk| match size {
            3 => PixelValue {
                r: chunk[0],
                g: chunk[1],
                b: chunk[2],
                a: 255,
            },
            _ => PixelValue {
                r: chunk[0],
                g: chunk[1],
                b: chunk[2],
                a: chunk[3],
            },
        }))
    }
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=cc409b6d75027a2bbd5c3ab527cdf8c4)

Notice that for the example I changed a few types I did not had access to (`png_type`, and the `get_size` method).

Answer (score 1):

You can create an `ImageDataIntoPixelValueIterator` that implements `Iterator` and use it as `type IntoIter`. NB: I've removed `png_type` from `ImageData` in order to make this code [reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and pretended that the alpha channel is always present:

```rust
struct ImageData {
    bytes: Vec<u8>,
    width: u32,
    height: u32,
    is_srgb: bool,
}

struct PixelValue {
    r: u8,
    g: u8,
    b: u8,
    a: u8,
}

impl IntoIterator for ImageData {
    type Item = PixelValue;
    type IntoIter = ImageDataIntoPixelValueIterator;

    fn into_iter(self) -> Self::IntoIter {
        ImageDataIntoPixelValueIterator {
            bytes: self.bytes,
            index: 0,
        }
    }
}

struct ImageDataIntoPixelValueIterator {
    bytes: Vec<u8>,
    index: usize,
}

impl Iterator for ImageDataIntoPixelValueIterator {
    type Item = PixelValue;

    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<PixelValue> {
        // assumes that self.bytes.len() is a multiple of four.
        // this should probably be asserted somewhere else
        if self.index >= self.bytes.len() {
            None
        } else {
            let res = PixelValue {
                r: self.bytes[self.index],
                g: self.bytes[self.index + 1],
                b: self.bytes[self.index + 2],
                a: self.bytes[self.index + 3],
            };
            self.index += 4;
            Some(res)
        }
    }
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=21db99f1c2a6f3f25298550176d2893c)

I've basically implemented [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30220832/12162258) for your specific needs. Please read that thoroughly, as it provides a wealth of explanatory information to help you understand why certain things will or will not work.