# Implementing diferent iterators on same data structure

Tags: rust, iterator

I want to have the option to return 2 completely different complex orders from an iterator. (referring to complex as not only reversed and normal order)

What would be the best way to accomplish this, i could have a method that saves the state before hand like:

```
/*for simple order*/
data_struct_instance.select_iter(data_struct_order::Simple);
let iter_simple = data_struct_instance.iter();

/*for complex order 1*/
data_struct_instance.select_iter(data_struct_order::Complex1);
let iter_complex1 = data_struct_instance.iter();
```

But i would rather avoid the internal state generated by the method `.select_iter()` is there a better way to accomplish this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use *different methods* returning different kinds of iterators. It is a common pattern, even found in the core library (see e.g. [`str::chars`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/primitive.str.html#method.chars) and [`str::char_indices`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/primitive.str.html#method.char_indices)), and comes with the advantage of enabling different return types for iterators without trait objects.

A complete example based on your code is not possible, but the public interface could be made into something like this:

```rust
struct DataStruct {
   // ...
}

impl DataStruct {
    pub fn simple_iter(&self) -> impl Iterator<SimpleData> + '_ {
        todo!()
    }

    pub fn complex_iter(&self) -> impl Iterator<ComplexData> + '_ {
        todo!()
    }
}
```

See also:

- [How to implement Iterator and IntoIterator for a simple struct?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30218886/how-to-implement-iterator-and-intoiterator-for-a-simple-struct)

Comment: An other example is `Vec` having 4 different iterators (iter and iter_mut from slices, into_iter, and drain), or HashMap with 8 (iter, iter_mut, into_iter, keys, into_keys, values, values_mut, into_values, and drain).